# How to get KDE cursor

Tags: kde, kubuntu

I just installed kubuntu-desktop, everything seems to be working fine and I am enjoying KDE. But the cursor is not the default KDE one, its the same old GNOME cursor. How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

This should give you a list of available cursor themes and which one is in "auto" mode. To change the default (auto) cursor, enter its corresponding number and press Enter.

For example:

```
~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
There are 7 choices for the alternative x-cursor-theme (providing /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme).

  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /etc/X11/cursors/oxy-white.theme          50        manual mode
  1            /etc/X11/cursors/core.theme               30        auto mode
  2            /etc/X11/cursors/handhelds.theme          20        manual mode
  3            /etc/X11/cursors/oxy-white.theme          50        manual mode
  4            /etc/X11/cursors/redglass.theme           20        manual mode
  5            /etc/X11/cursors/whiteglass.theme         20        manual mode
  6            /usr/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme   30        manual mode
  7            /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme   50        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

To get the standard KDE cursor to be the default, I would enter **0**

You may need to restart X to have it take effect (log out and back it.)

Comment: It's also useful when, for no good reason, You notice other cursors than currently selected in Tweak Tool for example - KDE one in my case. Thanks.