# How do I stop my mouse cursor from losing visibility? (or restore it's visibility)

Tags: mouse, kde, 19.04, cursor

After some uptime during usual and regular use, my mouse cursor will disappear (become invisible) and as you'd expect, it becomes very difficult to continue using my computer. Thanks to the visible responses from mousing over elements, I can still navigate, but it's like walking through the house with the lights off. Fortunately, rebooting does restore the mouse cursor's visibility. (Logging out and logging back in does not.)

It has now happened about 9 times and persisted through a few weeks of package upgrades. This is a problem that has arisen seemingly after the upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04. If there's a permanent fix that would be pleasant but I'd be satisfied with a way to restart my mouse cursor in terminal every time it disappears.

If I had to give a guess when I've seen it happen, it would be around the usage of programs/websites that change the cursor, but it's not something I can replicate immediately. (maybe it's a crash?)

OS: Ubuntu 19.04

Kernel: 5.0.0-31-generic

DE: KDE

WM: Kwin

Comment: Could you try switch to another cursor theme, as explained here https://askubuntu.com/a/36232/26246

Comment: I tried switching to another cursor theme using KDE's system settings, didn't work.

Comment: Does it disappear when it hits the top of screen edge?: https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/ab8dtd/pointer_disappears_at_top_of_screen/ If so it was fixed in Kernel 4.19 so there might be a regression in 5.0 and you can select previous kernel version in booting grub if you still have it there.

Comment: It doesn't disappear when it hits the top of the screen. If I had to give a guess when I've seen it happen, it would be around the usage of programs/websites that change the cursor, but it's not something I can replicate immediately. (maybe it's a crash?)